# Prevent width expansion on text line breaks in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

A simple flexbox layout is given showing an image next to arbitrary text, this is the desired result:

```css
#container {
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px; /* Dynamic */
}

#image {
  background: white;
  height: 50px; /* Dynamic */
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 50px; /* Dynamic */
}

span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* Make sure text also breaks when no hints are available */
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="image"></div>
  <span>long_text_should_be_<br />allowed_to_break</span>
</div>
```

However, for my use case I have to use `<wbr>` instead of `<br>` which breaks the centering behavior.

```css
#container {
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

#image {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="image"></div>
  <span>long_text_should_be_<wbr />allowed_to_break</span>
</div>
```

I understand that the latter is expected behavior as the flexbox children are blockified and line breaks in blocks do not shrink to the actual text width. But since it's working so seamlessly with `<br>` I am wondering if it can be tweaked to achieve the same result with `<wbr>` or alternative line break hints.

Goals:

- Must work in dynamic size environment, container and image sizes may vary
- Must fall back to a `break-all` behavior when no line break hints are given
- Must work with arbitrary text lengths with 1 to n characters
- Only has to work in a recent version of Chrome with LTR latin text

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `paragraph <p>` tag and css margin to give them top or bottom margins.

```css
#container {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 500px;
}

#image {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
#custombr{
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="image"></div>
  <h1>long_text_should_be_<p id="custombr">allowed_to_break</p></h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This introduces a forced line break though. I might as well use `<br>` then.

Comment: yeah!, but as you are looking for alternative so i suggest this one , btw you can also use div tag for same

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<br>` or `<wbr>`. This is not good if you will use a few languages in site.

This is simple solution in css:

```
h1 {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 400px;
}
```